# Choosing the right front-end framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, zurb-foundation

I'm looking into **Bootstrap** vs **Foundation** my criterias are:

- Lightweight
- Easily customized
- Easily build complex HTML layout
- Mobile / Responsive

In my past experience with Bootstrap, building layout from a designer mockup as a "pixel perfect" HTML was not trivial.

Your thoughts, ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, as it's quite subjective, and ultimately up to you, how comfortable you feel using one framework over another? It also depends on the design and project requirements etc. If 5 people say Bootstrap and 5 say Foundation....

Comment: That's right, I was aiming of hearing some opinions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation are both CSS frameworks, but they have a different purposes.

The primary goal of Bootstrap is fast prototyping of websites or web applications that have a base style. Since the styles are opinionated, that makes it more work to get it to match a custom design. It is heavily supported and a large community. It is built on Less and that can be a plus for some people.

Zurb Foundation 4 takes a different approach. It is more of a base framework for a project that will be customized fully based on project need. The styles are easily overridable. It is a great prototyping tool and it is not opinionated with styles. The grid system is great, and anyone can understand it. If you use Foundation your designer will think differently (they will keep mobile in mind more). It is built on SASS. That makes it easy to incorporate Compass sprite generation. I found the CSS classes in foundation to be easier for beginners to pick up and remember.

You can watch some of the Zurb presentation videos on the internet and they really help you understand why they built it.

I was working on my own framework to realize that everything I needed and more was already built into Foundation. The hardest part is understanding Compass and Sass. After that you will get the hang of Foundation easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really wanted to use Foundation. However, since my project needs to be IE8 compatible :( Foundation 4 is out ... so I'll probably use Bootstrap.

Comment: I just finished a site that needed to be ie8 compatible. I was worried at first but it turned out easier than I was expecting. Out of the box Zurb Foundation does not have support but you can easily add css to make the website look the way you want in IE8.

Comment: Thanks, could you be more specific regarding what was needed?

Comment: This page really helped out a lot. [https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210](https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210)

Comment: Besides that page I used .lt-ie9 in my styles. Compass really helps you out a lot with the & symbol. It is really powerful. That allows you to nest IE targeting by using .lt-ie9 &. {}. I will see about doing a write up on IE 8 with Foundation. There are a lot of tricks that can help make this process really easy.

Comment: I have created gist showing an example how to speed up your ie8 development. [https://gist.github.com/poeticninja/6011133](https://gist.github.com/poeticninja/6011133)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which of your criteria are more important.

Foundation is built for making complex, responsive websites, but it has a pretty big footprint if you want to use everything it has to offer. Bootstrap, on the other hand, is comparatively small but doesn't have anywhere near as much functionality built in. I can't speak to how easy it is to customize Bootstrap, but altering Foundation to fit your needs is very simple (especially if you use the SASS version).

It's a subjective choice: if your priority is to use something with a small footprint, go with Bootstrap. If having a big, responsive-ready library to work with is more important to you, go with Foundation.