# Usable frameworks for MySQL, PHP, HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, frameworks

For some years I used to code on PHP, MySQL and JS. And recently I opened for my self Twitter Bootstrap, and ready-to-use HTML templates. I feel that there are many other frameworks which can be usable for me.

There are something like 'Fundation" (I did not understand what it is), HTML5 boilerplate...

Could you point me into the usable names?

Comment: Do you want frontend frameworks (HTML, JS, CSS) or backend frameworks (MySQL, PHP). What do you want to build? There is a huge amount of frameworks and they span over a vast variety of needs.

Comment: Hi, @Merguez I need for both. Is there any article gathering them and explaining main points of those?

Comment: I still need to know, what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to build a webapplication (which calls for a mature JS MVC framework) or a more backend oriented "normal" website with some kind of self-build CMS?

Comment: @Merguez, I have to depend on the technologies available for the moment. I see that my question is too general to have any usable answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

- http://www.phpframeworks.com/ Check this for some common PHP Frameworks
- http://todomvc.com/ Check this for some common JS MVC Frameworks
- [Choosing the right front-end framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314434/choosing-the-right-front-end-framework)

Search deeper in Stackoverflow for more specific discussions about the topics. There are plenty of questions about choosing the right framework for your needs and things like that.

Every framework has its own pros and cons. Fitting them all into one post is impossible and answers are there to be found in the www.

A note to MySQL: There are no specific MySQL frameworks I know of, but what i think you meant was an abstraction for your requests to the database. This abstraction layer is already included in most PHP frameworks mentioned above (if not in all).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, for such detailed answer and the links you've provided. Looks like you've got my intention.